# I get error Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have search in others topics related and i couldn't get it.
I have this query :

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT TOP 10
         [ID] AS [DOCUMENTID],
         REPLACE([ImagePath], '\', '/') AS [FILENAME],
         9 AS TEMPLATEID,
         NULL AS ENCODEDRESULT,
         CASE 
            WHEN QA.DBValue IS NULL THEN QA.Value
            ELSE QA.DBValue 
         END AS RESULT,
         'Finished' AS [STATUS],
         QA.X AS [RLEFT],
         QA.Y AS [RTOP],
         QA.W AS [RWIDTH],
         QA.H AS [RHEIGHT],
         1 AS [QASTATUS],
         QA.[ASDTYPE] AS [ASDTYPE],
         QA.[DNNVALUE] AS [DNNRESULT],
         QA.[DNNSCORE] AS [DNNSCORE],
         CAST(QA.[ITEMDATE] AS DATE) AS [SCANDATE]
     FROM 
         [QA].[QAItems] QA WITH(NOLOCK)
     WHERE 
         QA.[PROCESSORTYPE] = 'F09'
         AND (QA.[DBVALUE] IS NOT NULL OR QA.[VALUE] IS NOT NULL)
         AND (QA.[DBVALUE] != 'null' OR QA.[VALUE] != 'null')
         AND QA.[DBVALUEPROCESSED] = 1) sub 
WHERE 
    CAST(sub.RESULT as date) >= '2019-06-01'
```

I get an error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I think is in the cast execution but I can't figure why or how to solve it.
The data type for Result is nvarchar. I think i have done the wrong condition.

Comment: You need to check the data type and their values of sub.RESULT.

Comment: So either `ITEMDATE` or `RESULT` aren't a date and time data type; why not when they appear like they should be? Also, do you have a ***good*** reason for using `NOLOCK`, or are you aware it can make your results *very* wrong? [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: It's impossible to guess what's wrong without knowing what the field types and contents are. One can *guess* that `RESULT` or `ITEMDATE`  are string fields instead of dates, which is a pretty bad bug.

Comment: Check your  result column having date datatype/varchar data type by using ISDate(Result)=0.

Comment: @B.Muthamizhselvi there's no reason to do that - in fact this simply covers up the bug, it doesn't fix anything. One can just look at the field types. If they are `varchar`, they need to change to a proper date type.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, we can see which row we get an error. some of the values may be in date format. one ore more data in not an dateformat. in that case we can see which row showing an error

Comment: @B.Muthamizhselvi the error is using the wrong type. After that, no matter which format is used (except one of the unambiguous formats like ISO8601), you *can't* know what those strings contain. What is 5/4/2019? April 4 or May 5? `ISDATE` won't catch or fix that. In fact, once this string gets into the database (eg because of a coding error), it's impossible to fix it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, Thank you to found my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem with the case expression :

```
CASE WHEN QA.DBValue IS NULL 
     THEN QA.Value
     ELSE QA.DBValue 
END AS RESULT
```

`CASE` expression would return single type data. So, `QA.Value` & `QA.DBValue` should have a same type data.

However, you can simply transit it with `COALESCE()` :

```
COALESCE(QA.DBValue, QA.Value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
where convert(date,sub.RESULT) = convert(date,'2019-06-01')
```

Comment: It's not the date literal. For `date` and `datetime2` types, `YYYY-MM-DD` is unambiguous, just like `YYYYMMDD`. It's far more likely that `sub.Result` is a string that can't be parsed as a date